# Add generic collection to LinkedList problem

Tags: c#, generics, collections

I have collection:

```
 class HashedData : IComparable
{
    string key;

    public string Key
    {
        get { return key; }
        set { key = value; }
    }
    string value;

    public string Value
    {
        get { return this.value; }
        set { this.value = value; }
    }


    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is HashedData)
        {
            HashedData hd = (HashedData)obj;
            return this.Key.CompareTo(hd.Key);
        }
        throw new NotImplementedException("Obiekt nie jest typu HashData");
    }
}
```

and method which use this collection as type od LInkedList:

```
        public void AddToHashTable(List<LinkedList<HashedData>> tablicaHashująca, HashedData data)
    {
        tablicaHashujaca[this.Hashuj(data.Key)].AddLast(**data**);
    }
```

I have error:

> Error  1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList.AddLast(string)' has some invalid arguments
>
> Error 2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Hashowanie.HashedData' to 'string'

***But why can't I add HashData object to LinkedList? It's any way to do this ?***

Comment: The only way I can see that you would get that error is if your first parameter was actually List<LinkedList<string>> because that's the only way it would be expecting a string for the AddLast call.  Does the code you posted match what you actually have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i am able to do it , if you define LinkedList < HashedData> then when you call AddLast , it will let you add the object of HashedData in the LinkedList.

i don't see any problem, can you please post more code

Answer (score 0):

```
data.Value
```

Not sure if that is what you want.